Jest Throws Error for Undefined Global Variable(Integration Testing)
I have an API request that returns some tokens I need for most requests.  I've placed a function in a setupFiles, and declared a variable using global.varName.  I attempt to use the variable in a beforeEach() hook.  But when I run Jest, before loading context, or executing the file in setupFiles, I get an error that the variable is not a function.
Background - This is an old MVC app, all data is embedded in html.  I am using Cheerio library for easier parsing.
Note: I have abstracted fetch http handler for re-usability, omitting that code.
jest.config.cjs
const jestConfig = {
  testMatch: ['**/tests/*.cjs'],
  setupFiles: ['./tests/lib/auth.cjs'],
  globals: {
    baseUrl: 'https://someUrl.com/',
  }
};

module.exports = jestConfig;

relevant function in auth.cjs
async function getReqVerificationValues() {
  const getCreateScriptScreen = await get(
    'someUri'
  );
  expect(getCreateScriptScreen.status).toBe(200);
  const getCreateScriptScreenText = await getCreateScriptScreen.text();
  global.createScriptDom = cheerio.load(getCreateScriptScreenText);
}

module.exports = { getAuthCookie, getReqVerificationValues };

Relevant section of scripts.test.cjs:
beforeEach(() => {
  const prescriberIdList = global
    .createScriptDom('[id=PrescriberId]')
    .children()
    .match(/(?<=option value=")(?!\s*$).+(?=")/g);
});

Error Message:
TypeError: global.createScriptDom is not a function

It seems that Jest does not like setupFiles to contain more than one function.  This is not clear from the docs, but by moving my second function to it's own file, and adding another entry in setupFiles[], both functions are now executed before tests run.
As Jest is not really designed for integration testing, chalking this up as another piece of that very intentional limitation.
